# При одновременной работе pytorch и sounddevice ничего не происходит но при убирании последнего программа начинает работать в чём проблема?

Tags: python, pytorch

я делаю голосового ассистента на python и появилась такая проблема что при включении sounddevice программа не работает при этом если библиотеку убрать то работа кода возобновляется. код прикладываю. версия питона 3,9.

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v3_1_ru' # другая версия русского
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True


device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id,
                                     trust_repo=True) # <- доверяем репозиторию

model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

def speak(what):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=what+"..",
                            speaker=speaker,
                            sample_rate=sample_rate,
                            put_accent=put_accent,
                            put_yo=put_yo)
    sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
    time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
    sd.stop
speak('Привет')
```

Comment: В заголовке должно брать краткое описание твой проблемы, а не что ты делаешь.

Answer (score 0):

проблема заключалась в конфликте `torchaudio` и `sounddevice`.

я просто перенёс импорт последнего непосредственно перед его использованием.

```
import torch
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v3_1_ru' # другая версия русского
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True


device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id,
                                     trust_repo=True) # <- доверяем репозиторию

model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

def say(text):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                            speaker=speaker,
                            sample_rate=sample_rate,
                            put_accent=put_accent,
                            put_yo=put_yo)
    import sounddevice as sd
    sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
    time.sleep((len(audio) / sample_rate)+1.2)
    sd.stop()
```

Comment: Отметьте этот ответ как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).